# Tell web browser that login failed so it doesn't ask to remember the password

Tags: http, browser

I'm writing a login system for a website, but when the user gets the login credentials wrong the browser (I've tried both Firefox and Chrome) still asks if the user wants to save the password.  How can I tell the browser that there was a login failure, so that it knows not to ask the user to save the bad credentials?

I've tried sending HTTP status codes of 403 and 500 (instead of the normal 200), but neither work.  Is there a way to do what I want?

P.S. I don't want to use the HTTP 401 authentication mechanism as I want to use an HTML form to login, not some browser dialog box.

Comment: Hmm, weird, I thought Chrome was actually expecting a 2XX response in order to show that dialog.

Comment: I think we should tell "browser makers" instead! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at [Chrome's Source Code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/password_manager/core/browser/password_manager.cc) to determine how this works (See `OnPasswordFormsRendered`), it is doing some heuristics to determine this. The way it appears to be doing this is:

1. User submits a form
2. Wait for the page to finish loading
3. Is the same form still visible? If yes, assume the form is being presented due the an invalid username or password.

When a user logon fails; they should be presented with the same form again. It would seem that your "Logon Failed" screen is too different from your original logon screen for the browser to see they are the same form.

<strike>It doesn't appear that HTTP Status Code makes a difference for offering to save the password.</strike>

Newer versions of Chrome [take in to account](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/password_manager/chrome_password_manager_client.cc?rcl=1473247219&l=416) the HTTP status code. If the status code is between 400 and 600, then it will not offer to save the password.

The other details are fairly well documented with comments in the same source file.

Comment: Neat. IE10 and below do not have a heuristic like this.

Comment: @EricLaw: I'd be curious to know how IE does it; but I can't seem to find the source for it anywhere ;-).

Answer (score -1):

Try http 401 unauthorized: "Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication is possible but has failed or not yet been provided." (Wikipedia quote).

EDIT: sorry. Didn't read your question well enough.

Comment: 10.4.2 401 Unauthorized

The request requires user authentication. The response **MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field** (section 14.47) containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource.